# Two authors having the same lastname in the same BIB entry

Tags: bibtex, footcite

I have two authors having the same lastname (because they are spouses) like this:

```
@BOOK{something,
  author     = {Pierre Curie and Marie Curie},
  title      = {Some shared publication},
}
```

So, I can use it twice in a `\footcite` command. In the first occurrence the rendering is “Pierre Curie and Marie Curie. *Some shared publication*”.

But in the second occurrence I get “Curie and Curie. op cite.”.

So, I have two questions:

1. Is it a normal and wanted behavior in the citation style?
2. How to get something like “The Curies” in this kind of case?

Comment: What you’re asking for is unlikely to be used in academic writing as the first option is correct. Furthermore the phrase “The Curies” doesn’t really mean the same thing as Pierre Curie and Marie Curie. For example you can say “Pierre Curie and Marie Curie wrote the first half and the second half of this article, respectively” but you can’t say “The Curies wrote the first half and the second half of this article respectively”. When we use names in citations we’re not referring to the people themselves but the people as authors which is why the Curie and Curie citation is the correct one.

Comment: You might need to distinguish between the authors at some point for their individual works, but for their joint publications, there's nothing wrong with “Curie & Curie”. So, yes, normal and wanted behavior.

Comment: It will also depend on the citation style used.